# What's this part? Hanging from left rear of Subaru 99 legacy.

Tags: subaru, part-identification

After driving a bit yesterday I came home and noticed that a part seemed to be hanging down from the rear left section of my car. The car is a 99 Subaru Legacy. Can anyone tell me what this is?

[image]

Comment: Can you tell where it connects to? and it may help to clarify driver or passenger side.

Comment: In addition to @John Dream 's question, can you try and figure out where it used to be? I looks rusted, so it should have broken off of something on the car. If you can get another picture of what I have asked some one might be able to help.

Comment: as a blind guess it looks to be potentially the housing for a bulb of some kind but it is very difficult to tell, maybe check to see if all of your lights function in the rear of the car? brakes reverse etc

Answer (score 9):

It's the EVAP vent solenoid. And I think you mean right rear.

[image]

Comment: Good answer @Ben, I did not even think of that. That is the most obvious part that has electrical connectors at the rear. How did I forget it.